# How to change interpreter using venv?

Tags: python-3.x, virtualenv

I have a project that exists in `~/Allen/project1` and used `venv` to create an isolated environment: `python3 -m venv ~/Allen/project1`.

The project I am doing requires Python 3.6, but my current Python3 is 
`python3 --version`: `Python 3.5.1` and my default OS X python is 2.7.10, neither of which is the correct python version.

How do I get configure a Python 3.6 interpreter inside my virtual environment.

Note that I'm using the newer `venv` instead of `virtualenv` although I don't think that should make too much of a difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to run `venv` with the appropriate python version, so install Python3.6 and run `python3.6 -m venv`

Comment: Thanks, I deleted python3.5 and installed 3.6 using brew.